# How to navigate to a composable screen from a notification with deeplinks?

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I want to navigate to a composable screen when clicking on a notification that contains data like title, body, and an id. This id should be passed to the composable when the route is created.

```
object Screen : AppDestination("screen/{id}") {
fun createRoute(id: String): String {
    return "screen/$id"
}
```

This is my composable screen navigation

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.screenGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    composable(
        route = Screen.route,
              arguments = listOf(navArgument("id") { type = NavType.StringType },
        navArgument("idnotation") { type = NavType.StringType }),
    deepLinks = listOf(
        navDeepLink {
            uriPattern = "myapp://screennavigation/idnotation={idnotation}"
        }
    ) {
        Screen(
            payloadId = it.arguments?.getString("id"),
        )
    }
}
```

The "id" is the when a certain item from a list is clicked to navigate to it.

The "idNotation" is the id that i get from the notification.

How can I pass the idNotation to the route if i'm getting it in the deeplink after the route is createRoute is called?

I tested how i'm passing the Id to the intent inside a pending intent for a notification and that works, i'm getting it correctly, I'm just not sure how to pass it to the route.

Comment: Did you [read the documentation specifically about creating deep links for use in notifications](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#deeplinks)?

Comment: I did now, thanks, seems like it's passing the id but when getting it to go to the route, it crashes the app, could it be that it's a wrong id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your deep link is

```
"myapp://screennavigation/idnotation={idnotation}"
```

Which means that the value of the `{idnotation}` placeholder will be put into your arguments with the key `idnotation`. If you want it to instead fill in the `id` field (to match your route and `arguments` list), then you'll want to use `{id}`:

```
uriPattern = "myapp://screennavigation/idnotation={id}"
```